# Replace NaNs with another value took from two other columns

Tags: python

On a dataframe, I used `groupby` and `mean` to create below table:

Code:

```
df.groupby(['Pclass','Sex'])['Age'].mean()
```

Result:

```
Class  Sex       
1.0     female    36.893130
        male      41.103490
2.0     female    27.499223
        male      30.815380
3.0     female    22.185329
        male      25.962264
```

And now, I want to `fillna` values from `[Age]` column (*on main dataframe*) using the results of above table.

- So, if the Age of a person is NaN and that person was in class 2 and the sex was male, it should be filled with 30.81
- I was thinking of using a code like this `if (df.loc[i, 'Pclass']==x) & (df.loc[i, 'Sex']=='female')` in a `for-loop`, but couldn't find a good way to do that.

Comment: FYI: The main dataframe has more than 1000 rows and 10 features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
df['Age'] = df.groupby(['Pclass','Sex']).Age.transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. And may I know what is the difference between ```.transform``` and ```.apply``` for this code? Why did you use this instead of .apply?